# How can I integrate a torrent video player in my app?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, torrent

I am building an android app. Want to know how can I stream torrent into a video player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [TorrentStream-Android library](https://github.com/TorrentStream/TorrentStream-Android). Currently it's the best solution for play torrents